# org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: empresa.Empleados

Tags: mysql, hibernate, netbeans, hql

I have a configuration of hibernate with two tables in Mysql and the files of configuration of Pojo are the following:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="empresa.Departamentos" table="departamentos" catalog="empresa2" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="deptno" type="int">
            <column name="deptno" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="dnombre" type="string">
            <column name="dnombre" length="15" />
        </property>
        <property name="loc" type="string">
            <column name="loc" length="15" />
        </property>
        <set name="empleadoses" table="empleados" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="deptno" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="empresa.Empleados" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="empresa.Empleados" table="empleados" catalog="empresa2" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="empno" type="short">
            <column name="empno" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="departamentos" class="empresa.Departamentos" fetch="select">
            <column name="deptno" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="apellido" type="string">
            <column name="apellido" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="oficio" type="string">
            <column name="oficio" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="dir" type="java.lang.Short">
            <column name="dir" />
        </property>
        <property name="fechaalt" type="date">
            <column name="fechaalt" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="salario" type="java.lang.Float">
            <column name="salario" precision="6" />
        </property>
        <property name="comision" type="java.lang.Float">
            <column name="comision" precision="6" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Next, when I execute the following sentence in hql:
select e from Empleados e where e.departamentos.deptno in (select d.deptno from Departamentos d where d.loc='London')
It gives me the following error:
org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: empresa.Empleados
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(HbmBinder.java:2557)
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder$CollectionSecondPass.secondPass(HbmBinder.java:2808)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1695)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1424)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
Regards,
Javier

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
select e.apellido 
from Empleados e 
where e.departamentos.deptno in 
  (select d.deptno 
   from Departamentos d 
   where d.loc='Sevilla')
```